# How to create a list of mutable integers in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, immutability

I have a very long list of integers `my_list`, together with an equivalence relation `~` on the set of indices. I need to define a new list `new_list` with the same set of indices by (in pseudocode)

```
new_list[i] = sum over all j with j~i of my_list[j]
```

Since this is a very long list, to save time I wanted to do the following. First, break the collection of indices `I` into equivalence classes `I/~`, and then for each equivalence class `C` write

```
for i in C:
    new_list[i] = C_sum
    C_sum += my_list[i]
```

The hope was that for each `i` I could define `new_list[i]` to POINT to the variable `C_sum`, and then when I modify `C_sum` in the for loop, `new_list[i]` would still point to `C_sum` which would now be larger. But this didn't work. I thought that a) lists store references to objects, and that b) the += command modified the existing value rather than re-binding the variable to a new value. Where did I go wrong, and is there a way I can accomplish something like what I wanted -- namely, defining `new_list` on a single equivalence class inside just one loop?

Comment: Briefly: yes, the list is mutable. However, the integers it holds are not. You can wrap each integer in its own list, but you probably have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks, that solves the first part of my question. I suppose += is only an "in-place" modification for mutable data types.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I disagree that my question is a duplicate of the post you linked, as that post doesn't address the second (and much more important) part of my question.